# Can you please tell me what's wrong in the below code?

Tags: c++, variables

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    int i=99998;
    long long int sq = i*i;
    std::cout<<sq;
    return 0;
}
```

I ran these code and it gives me output as 1409665412 but 99999*99999=9999800001
Can you please tell me why its so?????

Comment: i is an int, int * int is still int; you need to cast to long long first

Comment: Because `9999800001` is larger than a 32 bit integer `i` needs to be a 64bit integer perhaps `int64_t` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer

Answer (score 1):

I guess multiply int by int can't give you number higher than 2,147,483,647.
To be right u need to convert your int to long long before pass it sq. You can do that like this:

```
long long int sq=(long long int) i*i;
```

And your multiply will be okey!
Or you can just set 'i' as long long int, to be okey from the beginning!